# How to implement nested subtables with PrimeFaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

[image]

As you can see from the above table made in the excel sheet, I want to create a table using Primefaces datatable.
The table rows has to be grouped based on two sets of columns(first 2 columns, and first 7 columns), represented by Red and Yellow box, also I need to add summary row which will calculate the sum of values inside "Invia Totale" column for both inner group and outer group represented by blue boxes.
I have already grouped the DB records according to the logic of the table data.

**My xhtml File:**

```
<p:dataTable id="tbltotaliFatture" widgetVar="tbltotaliFatture"
value="#{bbean.outGroupList}" var="outerGroup"
emptyMessage="#{global['msgNessunRisultatoTrovato']}"
scrollRows="10" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400"
scrollWidth="100%">
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width:250px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['label_centrale']}" />
            <p:column style="width:130px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['label_file']}" />
            <p:column style="width:110px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['label_compagnia']}" />
            <p:column style="width:110px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['label_anno_rif']}" />
            <p:column style="width:110px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['label_mese_rif']}" />
            <p:column style="width:110px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['lbl_anno_competenza']}" />
            <p:column style="width:110px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['lbl_tipo_costo']}" />
            <p:column style="width:130px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['lbl_modalita_pagamento']}" />
            <p:column style="width:150px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['lbl_totale_inviato']}" />
            <p:column style="width:150px"
                headerText="#{quadraturaFattureEura['lbl_totale_in_errore']}" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:subTable var="innerGroup" value="#{outerGroup.innerGroupList}">
        <p:subTable var="row" value="#{innerGroup.mappedServiceMBeanList}">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="dscCentrale"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.codCentrale}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="dscFile"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.codFile}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="codMulticompagnia"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.codMultiCompag}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="annoRiferimento"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.annoRiferi}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="meseRiferimento"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.meseRiferi}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="annoCompetenza"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.annoCompetenza}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="tipoCosto"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.tipoCosto}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="modalitaPagamento"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.modalitaPagamento}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="totaleInviato"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.totaleInviato}">

                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="totaleInErrore"
                    styleClass="value-text text-right"
                    value="#{row.totaleInErrore}">

                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:columnGroup>
                <p:column style="background-color: #F0F0F0;" colspan="8" />
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText id="innerTotal"
                        styleClass="value-text text-right"
                        value="#{innerGroup.innerTotal}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="background-color: #F0F0F0;" />
            </p:columnGroup>
            <p:columnGroup>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column style="background-color: #F0F0F0;" colspan="9" />
                    <p:column style="background-color: #F0F0F0;">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="value-text text-bold text-right"
                            value="#{outerGroup.outerTotal}">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>
        </p:subTable>
    </p:subTable></p:dataTable>
```

Java Bean classes:-
**QuadraturaFattureEuraOuterGroup.java**

```
public class QuadraturaFattureEuraOuterGroup {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 947989833069960727L;
private String outerTotal;

private List<QuadraturaFattureEuraInnerGroup> innerGroupList;
}
```

**QuadraturaFattureEuraInnerGroup.java**

```
public class QuadraturaFattureEuraInnerGroup implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7411230855825585398L;

private String innerTotal;

private List<QuadraturaFattureEuraMBean> mappedServiceMBeanList;
```

}

**QuadraturaFattureEuraMBean.java**

```
 public class QuadraturaFattureEuraMBean {
// list of properties being fetched from data-base and to be rendered as UI table rows
```

}

My table data is not rendered, and I don't get any error either.
Please help me on this, as I didn't find any solution with the scenarios like mine.

Comment: Just a warning PF SubTables are deprecated and they are recommending not to use them in the future. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2269